# Escape awk command

Tags: unix, awk, aix

I have got a unix(aix) command which includes a small awk script. It works and here it is...

```
ps -eaf | awk 'ARGIND == 1 {$pids[$0] = 1} ARGIND > 1 {if ($2 in pids) printf("%s\n",$0)}' /home/richard/myFile.flg -
```

When I run this command from a different box using ssh it doesn't work.

```
ssh myuser@myOtherBox ps -eaf | awk 'ARGIND == 1 {$pids[$0] = 1} ARGIND > 1 {if ($2 in pids) printf("%s\n",$0)}' /home/richard/myFile.flg -
```

I've worked out that I need to quote the awk script and escape some characters in the awk command but I can't get the escapes right.

Would someone pls help me with quoting the awk part of the script and escaping what is required.

thanks

Comment: "it doesn't work" - elaborate plz.

Comment: `$pids[$0]` should be `pids[$0]`. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter: that's true and I fixed my answer. But the stray dollar sign doesn't affect the observed behaviour of the script.

Comment: yes, agree, w your answer that script is executing locally. I just didn't have time to write that. Good luck to all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In cases like this you need double escaping, this should work:

```
ssh myuser@myOtherBox "ps -eaf | awk \"ARGIND == 1 {\\\$pids[\\\$0] = 1} ARGIND > 1 {if (\\\$2 in pids) printf(\\\"%s\n\\\",\\\$0)}\" /home/richard/myFile.flg -"
```

Comment: thank you the double escaping worked here and was the easiest solution

Answer (score 4):

What happens when you execute

```
ssh myuser@myOtherBox ps -eaf | ...
```

is that `ps -eaf` is run on the other box, and the output is returned; `ssh` then writes the output it receives to its own stdout, which is (locally) redirected through the command `...`; in this case, an awk command.

Unfortunately, (I assume) `/home/richard/myFile.flg` is on the remote mache and not the local machine, so the awk command fails.

To get the whole thing to run on the remote machine, you need to provide it as a single argument; one way which doesn't require much quoting effort is to use a here-doc:

```
ssh myuser@myOtherBox "$(cat<<"END"
ps -eaf |
awk 'ARGIND == 1 {pids[$0] = 1}
     ARGIND > 1  {if ($2 in pids) printf("%s\n",$0)}' \
    /home/richard/myFile.flg -
END
)"
```

Note that `printf("%s\n",$0)` is really just a complicated way of writing `print`, so you could simplify the remote command quite a bit. But you would still need to deal with the single quotes in the awk command:

```
ssh myuser@myOtherBox '
    ps -eaf |
    awk '"'"'ARGIND == 1 {pids[$0] = 1; next}
             $2 in pids {print}'"'"' \
        /home/richard/myFile.flg -'
```

To understand `'"'"'`, you need to break it into pieces:

```
'      close '-quoted string
"'"    A (quoted) '
'      open another '-quoted string
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use bash's $'STRING' syntax, then things remain quite
readable; in this case one only has to escape the single-quotes and
backslashes:

```
$'ps -eaf |
  awk \'
  ARGIND == 1 {$pids[$0] = 1} 
  ARGIND > 1 {if ($2 in pids) printf("%s\\n",$0)}\' /home/richard/myFile.flg -'
```